# How to fill a 2D array using a for-loop or nested for-loops in java

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array and its type is object. I want to fill this 2D array. But I have no idea about this .

This is what I know already.

```
public TableRowHeaderTest(List<Employee> list){
    Object rowData1[][] = new Object[list.size()][];

    Object columnNames1[] ={"HEADER 1", "HEADER 2", "HEADER 3", "HEADER 4", "HEADER 5", "HEADER 6", "HEADER 7", "HEADER 8", "HEADER 9", "HEADER 10", "HEADER 11", "HEADER 12", "HEADER 13"};        

    JTable table1 = new TableWithRowHeader(rowData1, columnNames1);
    table1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(120);
    JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(table1);
    scrollPane1.setColumnHeaderView(null);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(jPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(scrollPane1);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

    public class TableWithRowHeader extends JTable{

    private TableRowHeader rowHeader;

    public TableWithRowHeader(final Object[][] rowData, final Object[] columnNames)
    {
        super(rowData, columnNames);
        rowHeader = new TableRowHeader(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureEnclosingScrollPane()
    {
        // This is required as it calls a private method...
        super.configureEnclosingScrollPane();

        Container parent = SwingUtilities.getUnwrappedParent(this);
        if (parent instanceof JViewport)
        {

            JViewport port = (JViewport) parent;
            Container gp = port.getParent();
            if (gp instanceof JScrollPane)
            {

                JScrollPane scrollPane = (JScrollPane) gp;
                JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport();
                if (viewport == null || SwingUtilities.getUnwrappedView(viewport) != this)
                {
                    return;
                }
                scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(null);
                scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(rowHeader);
            }
        }
    }

}

public class TableRowHeader extends JTableHeader{

    private JTable table;

    public TableRowHeader(JTable table)
    {
        super(table.getColumnModel());
        this.table = table;

        table.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(new TableColumnModelListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void columnAdded(TableColumnModelEvent e)
            {
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void columnRemoved(TableColumnModelEvent e)
            {
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent e)
            {
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent e)
            {
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
            {
                // Don't care about this, want to highlight the row...
            }
        });
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
            {
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public JTable getTable()
    {
        return table;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        Dimension size = new Dimension();
        JTable table = getTable();
        if (table != null)
        {
            TableColumnModel model = table.getColumnModel();
            if (model != null)
            {

                for (int index = 0; index < model.getColumnCount(); index++)
                {

                    TableColumn column = model.getColumn(index);
                    TableCellRenderer renderer = column.getHeaderRenderer();
                    if (renderer == null)
                    {

                        renderer = getDefaultRenderer();

                    }
                    Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, column.getHeaderValue(), false, false, -1, index);
                    size.width = Math.max(comp.getPreferredSize().width, size.width);
                    size.height += table.getRowHeight(index);

                }

            }
        }
        return size;

    }

    /**
     * Overridden to avoid propagating a invalidate up the tree when the
     * cell renderer child is configured.
     */
    @Override
    public void invalidate()
    {
    }

    /**
     * If the specified component is already a child of this then we don't
     * bother doing anything - stacking order doesn't matter for cell
     * renderer components (CellRendererPane doesn't paint anyway).
     */
    @Override
    protected void addImpl(Component x, Object constraints, int index)
    {
        if (x.getParent() == this)
        {
        } else
        {
            super.addImpl(x, constraints, index);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        g2d.setColor(getBackground());
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        JTable table = getTable();
        if (table != null)
        {

            int width = getWidth();

            TableColumnModel model = table.getColumnModel();
            if (model != null)
            {

                for (int index = 0; index < model.getColumnCount(); index++)
                {

                    TableColumn column = model.getColumn(index);
                    TableCellRenderer renderer = column.getHeaderRenderer();
                    if (renderer == null)
                    {

                        renderer = getDefaultRenderer();

                    }

                    boolean selected = table.getSelectedRow() == index;

                    Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, column.getHeaderValue(), selected, false, 0, index);

                    add(comp);
                    comp.validate();

                    int height = table.getRowHeight(index) - 1;
                    comp.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
                    comp.paint(g2d);
                    comp.setBounds(-width, -height, 0, 0);

                    g2d.setColor(table.getGridColor());
                    g2d.drawLine(0, height, width, height);

                    g2d.translate(0, height + 1);

                }

            }
        }
        g2d.dispose();
        removeAll();
    }

}
```

So , I want to fill this 2D array for above purpose .

Have any ideas ?

Thank you .

Comment: try something and see

Comment: @ScaryWombat :- What is something ?

Comment: Please ask a well formed question with example code of what you have attempted. For more information see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: 1) Declare your 2d array 2) declare a loop 3) insert into your 2d array

Comment: @ScaryWombat :- See updated post .

Comment: Why are they `Object`s?  Why not Strings

Comment: @ScaryWombat :-  Can I use String for this ? I don't know about it .

Comment: This list includes same type Objects . Like Student , Employee etc .

Comment: Firstly, why are you making an array of Objects rather than the actual objects you want in the array (I presume Strings based on your code). Secondly, please explain exactly what you want. Are you trying to fill a multidimensional array or display a JTable with Swing? If you are trying to fill a multidimensional array then why do you have a JTable object at all?

Comment: @john01dav :- I have done some edits to my post .

Comment: But the code that you have added is not relevant at all

Comment: @ScaryWombat :- But this is my purpose .

Comment: I used this code to set columns in vertical view . Then I wanted to fill each column according to this vertical view .

Comment: @Barrier You just added more code. If you want help you need to better explain what it is you are trying to do and what you have already tried. It is also important to try Googling for a solution to your problem and explain why the solutions you found didn't work. Also, try explaining the purpuse of your code in plain English -- what should the end user see?

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

`int[][] values = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };`

try it with string values.